# How to automatically turn off hard drive when not used?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, gnome-disk-utility

I have a noisy hard drive I rarely use and want to silent.
I would like to put it in sleep mode after some time (20 sec) when it's not mounted on the system.

The `gnome-disks` utility shows a "standby timeout" option:
[image]
[image]

The hard drive never gets to sleep automatically; I can manually put it to sleep/wake it up with the gear menu:
[image]

Why does my drive doesn't automatically go to sleep?
How can I make it go to sleep automatically after no activity?

Answer (score 3):

This part from [Put HDDs in standby after X minutes using hdparm doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137577/put-hdds-in-standby-after-x-minutes-using-hdparm-doesnt-work) might help:

> Is AHCI enabled in your BIOS? If not try turning it on and re-trying.

Comment: Since you think that answer applies, the question should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @andy256 However, I think that's the only part that helps. I don't think any of the other stuff helps.

Comment: @bhargavxx: I'll ask a mod to convert this to a comment...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/504178)

Comment: @Pilot6 Isn't that what I did?

Comment: @Pilot6 Isn't that what I did?