# HDD Standby - High Load Cycle Count

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, battery

I know that there are many question about this topic. However, I did not find a solution for my situation.

**What I want to achieve:** My HDD (Hitachi Travelstar 5k1000) in my notebook should go into standby after ~5min and the load cycle value should only increase moderately.

**My setup:** Ubuntu 14.04 is installed on an SSD and the HDD is only used for data. I checked the APM values for the HDD via `sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda` and got

> /dev/sda:
>    APM_level  = 254

for AC and for battery

> /dev/sda:
>    APM_level  = 128

Right now the HDD never goes into standby mode. However, if my notebook runs on battery, the Load_Cycle_Count increases tremendously (2-3 per *minute*).

As I understand it, an APM level <=127 allows the HDD to go into standy (=spin down?), so APM=128 prevents standby but still increases LCC heavily. What are my options to achieve my goal?

Maybe related: Up to now I do not use any laptop-mode-tools or TLP etc. If it is useful/helpful I would also appreciate solutions which make use of TLP (for example).

Comment: To get it to standby after 5min, you need to add `-S 60` option, as in `hdparm -S 60`. There are several ways to automate it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/711019/how-to-automatically-turn-off-hard-drive-when-not-used?lq=1

Comment: But I need APM <=127 for this to work, right? If I set APM to 127 and usee `hdparm -S 60` the disk goes into standby immediately and does not wait 5min. AHCI is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Try it both ways, if unsure.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation).

**LCC:** as a first guess i suggest to [configure](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)

```
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT=192
```

and monitor LCC afterwards.

**Spindown:** configure

```
 DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC="60 0"
 DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT="60 0"
```

(assuming HDD is sda)

It's all in the [TLP FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#disks) btw.

ps. some more explanation: there is no conflict using APM >= 128 (hdparm -B) and spindown (-S) at the same time (i use it myself). It's however important to always set spindown after (or together with) APM because hdparm -B clears the -S setting. TLP considers this automatically.